Custom provider in next-auth (auth.js)
I want to make OIDC provider in my next.js app.
I need to implement functionallity for some provider that is not built in.
If anyone has any advice it would be appriciated.
Thanks :)
i did try following this https://next-auth.js.org/v3/configuration/providers
but i get that type is not assignable.
i tried to import types like
OAuthConfig, OAuthUserConfig but I cannot
any idea on how to do it
i did try with oidc-client library
const userManagerConfig = {
    authority: 'auth',
    client_id: 'clid',
    redirect_uri: 'http://localhost:3001/signin-callback',
    response_type: 'code',
    client_secret:'secret',
    scope: 'openid profile email',
    post_logout_redirect_uri: 'http://localhost:3000',
    userStore: new WebStorageStateStore({ store: window.localStorage }),
    loadUserInfo: true,
};

and i manage to get redirection and get tokens, but I don't want to import new library if I don't need it
EDIT: I managed to do it, error message for type was misleading, when I extracted it to constant it did not show any error message...
just some Tyoescript or IDE "bug"...
